# How risky is development against SQL Server 2008 with production on SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, development-environment

My dev environment has SQL Server 2008 installed. I have an asp.net 1.1 site in production using SQL Server 2005. I'd rather not install SQL Server 2005 on my development environment. How risky would this be? What kinds of things might cause problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems worth looking at this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

which describes compatibility levels which can be set against a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're using ASP.NET 1.1, I think that's more your risky part then anything else. If you have a proper ORM layer, you need not worry about the DB version at all.

If you don't have a proper ORM layer, consider changing to [using one](http://nhforge.org) (but most modern ORM's have come into major usage after ASP.NET 1.1 and do not support anything before 2.0, so you'll have to upgrade sometime, I'm afraid).

Comment: in the meantime: consider the link from *spender*. I've done your scenario for years (using modern software myself, using dated software with clients because they have to). It never got me into trouble, but I usually stay on the "safe path": I don't use version-specific SQL, ever (if I can help it)

Comment: Tx Michael, I keep typing the longer version (which brings you to nhforge anyway). A. updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but make sure not to use the Date type in development. Use DateTime as that's supported in both versions.